# Flattening out base of object using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing

Flattening out base of object using geometry nodes.

I have an object.

[image: img 1]

And would like the base to be flattened out using geometry nodes **without having to type in each face index manually**.

I know I can `extrude` - `scale` - `z` - `0` but I'm having some trouble with geometry nodes since the shape is "awkward".  (**I would like a flat base since it will be 3D printed but I would like to flatten the base using geometry nodes**)

[image: img2]

My thought was to select the bottom faces do the `extrude` and `scale` - `z` - `0` but I'm picking up other faces (**see red arrows**).

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

Any ideas how to select just the bottom faces and flatten them out?

I did look at [Flattening out and dissolving faces using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258676/flattening-out-and-dissolving-faces-using-geometry-nodes) but the current shape I'm using has awkward angles that go back up.

**Update:**  This is a continuation from this question.
[Calculating and aligning the angles needed to create different corner connectors to join / create various polyhedrons using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296525/calculating-and-aligning-the-angles-needed-to-create-different-corner-connectors)

See attached Blend file.

[image]

**Update 2: To answer Markus comment about providing multiple examples.**

[image: pin1]

[image: pin2]

[image: pin several]

[image: pin several 2]

Blender file with the connectors.

[image]

Comment: One question: are there a lot of objects where you have to do this with an automated process? Otherwise, for 3D printing you have to get rid of all modifiers anyway and convert it all to a mesh object. So why not simply use the extrude + scale method? And if it's just for this one specific object, you can try to identify the faces by their IDs and use this selection to only flatten them.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes lots.  It's based from this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296525/calculating-and-aligning-the-angles-needed-to-create-different-corner-connectors   So it could be a lot,  Different types of connectors along with different types of polyhedra.

Comment: Okay, but if they look very individually different, I would not even know exactly how to define what criteria have to be met to select a face that should be flattened versus the rest of the mesh. And if we don't know how different they can be, how should we blindly find some methods to distinguish them and be sure that they work for all objects?

Comment: Did you generate the object(s) with GN? If so, you could probably mark the faces to be flattened during construction?

Comment: @RobinBetts it wasn't created directly in GN but each connector starts off separated, maybe alter the bottom of the connector before they are joined..  Thanks I'll look into it.

Comment: We could perhaps find the common denominator if you provided multiple examples.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  I added the example images with multiple connectors along with the blend file for it.

Comment: @RickT you don't actually display the connectors from the bottom, and in the .blend I see just one. Do you want to select the bottom-most vertex on $z$ axis ($x=0$, $y=0$) grow selection to neighboring faces, extrude them down and flatten (SZ0 keys)?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady strange I'll post it again. Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on info provided: out of the vertices not more than $0.001$ away from $z$ axis, find the minimum $z$, then find the index of that vertex, put weight on that vertex, let it 'spill' onto faces using *float* interpolation, select those faces and extrude them, but with no offset (you may want to change that), scale them to 0 by setting Z component to the lowest (therefore another attribute stat), merge by distance (needed because of zero extrusion).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: a slightly simpler setup would also work: https://i.imgur.com/6n0y3Pk.png

Comment: **If** the vertex is exactly in the center, I think that is a wonderful solution!

Comment: This is really a nice solution!